# Compare 2 images, get the coordinates of the difference among them

Tags: image, scripting, autoit

In order to solve a problem I'm having with an AutoIt, I need to compare 2 images of a Windows system UI.

The only difference they will have is a rectangle of a different color since the text will be highlighted. I need to know the location (X & Y, in pixels) of that rectangle, to instruct the script to click there.

Any software that can tell me the coordinates, in the same resolution as the screen, so I can click on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using autoit, make a little script like this :

```
#include <misc.au3>

HotKeySet("{Esc}","fin")
local $pos

func fin()
   Exit
EndFunc

While 1
   _GetPos()
WEnd


func _GetPos()
   $pos=MouseGetPos()
    If _ispressed("7B") Then
      SplashTextOn("MousePos", "X[" &  $Pos[0] & "]"& " - Y[" & $Pos[1] & "]",200,50)
      sleep(5000)
      SplashOff()
      EndIf
   Sleep(60)
EndFunc
```

Run it and when you press F12 it will give you the position of the mouse cursor for 5 secondes.

Esc to exit

Answer (score 0):

You can press the print screen button to get the image of the window in your clip board.  Then, paste the results in a Paintbrush window.  The bottom left hand corner should give you the x/y coordinates in the Paint window.  You may need to click view:status bar.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [ImageSearch UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/)

Download DLL from [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/65748-image-search-library/page-4).

Example usage:

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>

$x1=0
$y1=0

HotKeySet( "+s", "Start" )
HotKeySet( "+e", "end" )

While 1
   Sleep (100)
WEnd

Func Start()
   While 1
      $result = _ImageSearch("recycle2.bmp",1,$x1,$y1,0)
      if $result=1 Then
         MouseMove($x1,$y1,3)
         MsgBox(0,"Found","Found a empty recycle bin here...")
      EndIf
   WEnd
EndFunc

Func End()
   Exit
EndFunc
```